# IntelliJ/Lombok - Cannot resolve method 'setLastName(java.lang.String)'

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

IntelliJ does not resolve my setter-methods although

- I have installed the Lombok-plugin
- I have enabled annotation processing
- I have added the Lombok-Maven-dependency on my pom.xml

My classes:
TournamentController:

```
package ba2.demo.Service;

import ba2.demo.DTO.ArcherDTO;
import ba2.demo.DTO.DivisionDTO;
import ba2.demo.DTO.TournamentDTO;
import ba2.demo.Model.Archer;
import ba2.demo.Model.Tournament;
import ba2.demo.Repository.ArcherRepository;
import ba2.demo.Repository.DivisionRepository;
import ba2.demo.Repository.TournamentRepository;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class TournamentServiceImpl implements TournamentService {

    @Autowired
    private TournamentRepository tournamentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ArcherRepository archerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DivisionRepository divisionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public List<Tournament> getAllTournaments() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Tournament getTournamentById(int id) {
        Tournament obj = tournamentRepository.findById(id).get();
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public TournamentDTO createTournament(TournamentDTO tournamentDTO) {
        Tournament tournamentModel = new Tournament()
                .setName(tournamentDTO.getName())
                .setStatusCode(tournamentDTO.getStatusCode());
        tournamentRepository.save(tournamentModel);
        return modelMapper.map(tournamentModel, TournamentDTO.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void editTournament(TournamentDTO tournamentDTO) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteTournament(int id) {

    }

    @Override
    public ArcherDTO registerArcher(ArcherDTO archerDTO, DivisionDTO divisionDTO) {
        Archer archerModel = new Archer()
                .setFirstName(archerDTO.getFirstName())
                .setLastName(archerDTO.getLastName())
                .setDivisionName(divisionDTO.getName());
        archerRepository.save(archerModel);
        return modelMapper.map(archerModel, ArcherDTO.class);
    }
}
```

Archer-Model:

```
package ba2.demo.Model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Archer {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private Division division;

    private ShootingStyle shootingStyle;
}
```

ArcherDTO:

```
package ba2.demo.DTO;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

 
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ArcherDTO {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private String divisionName;
    private String shootingStyleName;
 }
```

The error message:
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getName()
location: variable tournamentDTO of type ba2.demo.DTO.TournamentDTO

Comment: The `getName()` error seems to be coming from either the `TournamentDTO` or `DivisionDTO` classes, not the Lombok classes which you actually showed us.  Please check that part of your code base.

Comment: Checked it, my TournamentDTO has name- and statusCode-Attributes as well as the Lombok-annotations.

Comment: Try the following: Invalidate Cache and Restart.  When you reload IntelliJ, do a Maven clean build, then try again.

Comment: Validated, restarted and cleaned, didn't work.

Comment: Please add the dependencies version (pom.xml) to the issue or share the link with uploaded project. Thank you